# How to change Recovery options of a Service by batch?

Tags: windows, batch, services

I'm creating a batch file to turn off `BITS`, but in order for it to **not** restart ,

I have to change **first failure**,**second failure** and **subsequent failure** to **take no action** ,
set **reset fail counter after** to **0**

Only thing I know is to do this

```
sc config BITS start= disabled
net stop BITS
```

I want to make a batch file that will **disable**,**stop** `BITS` and set the recovery options as

```
first failure:take no action
second failure:take no action
subsequent failure:take no action
reset fail counter after: 0
```

Comment: [There are lot of resources available around this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssehgal/2009/06/01/configuring-windows-services-using-command-prompt/). It doesn't appear you have looked at any of them and you are just asking for a cooked script

Comment: @pun although you thought of me in a bad way, the link you provided looks like what I need ,thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pun ,thank for the help, found a way

```
net stop BITS
sc config BITS start= disabled
sc failure "BITS"  actions= ""/0/""/0/""/0 reset= 0
```